# Deferring royalties for assets until revenue is earned

Tags: legal, intellectual-property

I am developing a game and I want to use some assets that are available online for a fixed price, I want to sell my game and actually make money off of it. I have contacted the owners and they will sell it to me for a fixed price to use commercially. However, I am on a very limited budget and don't really want to pay up front for the assets.

What I want to know is how to defer the costs contingent on whether I make any money. In other words, they give me the models, and then I promise to pay them back out of the first revenue. If the project dies, I'm  not out any money.

Other than my word as an honest guy, how could I convince them to agree to this? Would they charge me more because of risk involved?

Comment: Have you made any games before? Even just student projects (although commercial titles that you've released are better of course)? If so, that puts you in a much stronger negotiating position, since it is more likely that you will complete this game. As opposed to just "my word as an honest guy".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just negotiate with them. If they're willing to take a royalty, they will. If not, you'll have to get other assets.

Comment: Yep.  This is the correct answer.

Comment: Spend 10 seconds writing up a crap answer, get upvotes like crazy :P  Friggen Almo.

Comment: (I'm the first upvote on that comment, Jon.)